# Centering text inside rounded rectangle vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, center

I want center text inside rounded rectangle (both vertically and horizontally), and also center this banner on page too, not sure how to make this correctly. The other elements need be centered too. Please advice how to make things correctly.
Here is code:

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#rcorners {
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 6px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 40px;
}

body {
  background-image: url(images/blaunew.png);
  background-color: #001b33;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 14px;
}

#rcorners {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  Helvetica,
  sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 32px;
  Helvetica,
  sans-serif;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 20%;
  //font-size: 35px;       
}

footer {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>centered construction</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
      <h1 id="rcorners">Centered Text No1</h1>
      <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR </p>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <div>&copy; Lorem Ipsum Dolor </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `width: 450px;` and `height: 40px` from `#rcorners`.

Otherwise, if you want to keep it 450px wide, you may add `margin: auto` to `#rcorners`. It will solve your problem.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700');

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%; 
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

 #rcorners {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 6px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 20px; 
    /* width: 450px;
    height: 40px;     */
}
body {
    background-image: url(images/blaunew.png);
    background-color: #001b33;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Roboto';font-size: 14px;
}
#rcorners {
    font-family: 'Roboto';font-size:48px;font-weight:700; font-style:normal; Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
p {
    font-family: 'Roboto'; font-size: 32px; Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

.main { 
   margin-top: 20%;
//font-size: 35px;       
}

footer {
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
         <h1 id="rcorners">Centered Text No1</h1>
         <p>LOREM IPSUM DOLOR </p>
         </div>

    <footer>
        <div>&copy; Lorem Ipsum Dolor </div>
       </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: If not limit the width of button, it expands up to the full width of `#wrapper` (1066px)

Answer (score 0):

To center the button add `margin: 0 auto` and to center the text you can easily do it with flexbox I think. The code will look something like:

```
#rcorners {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can read more about centering with flexbox here: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Answer (score 0):

I have edit your CSS. but i dont get why you gave height on your  #rcorners element. Hope this will help you

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%; 
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

 #rcorners {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 6px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 450px;
    /*height: 40px; */ /*it is less height for 2 line text*/   
}
body {
    background-image: url(images/blaunew.png);
    background-color: #001b33;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Roboto';font-size: 14px;
}
#rcorners {
    font-family: 'Roboto';font-size:48px;font-weight:700; font-style:normal; Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
p {
    font-family: 'Roboto'; font-size: 32px; Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

.main { 
   margin-top: 20%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display:  inline-block;
    width: auto;
/*font-size: 35px; */      
}

footer {
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: @minto you have dynamic data that you want to align center (vertical or horizontal) ?

Comment: Just static text.

Comment: @minto, but in this div text is horizontal and vertical align. What exactly you want ?